# Array of functions in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, list, wolfram-mathematica

I understand that Mathematica functions "A" and "B" can be defined as in this simple example

```
A[x_] := 10*x;
B[y_] := 100*y;
```

I want to populate a collection of elements (list/table/array, whichever is appropriate) with such functions and do this through a (for or while) loop.

For example, the 1st element is A[x], the 2nd is B[y], and it keeps repeating until, say I have a list of 10 functions.

Let's call the list MyFunctions. Is there a way to assign function properties to the array itself, so it assigns value to the functions? That is, can I somehow write MyFunctions[x_,y_] which contains those A[x] and B[y] functions in its elements?

I wanted something like this:

```
MyFunctions[[1]] = A[x];
MyFunctions[[2]] = B[y];
```

Then you can evaluate both functions at once with MyFunctions[1,2], so

```
MyFunctions[1,2][[1]] yields 10
MyFunctions[1,2][[2]] yields 200
```

It appears that I can hard-code this, as shown here

```
A[x_] := 10 x;
B[y_] := 100 y;
MyFunctions[x_, y_] := {A[x], B[y]};
MyFunctions[1, 2] yields {10, 200}
```

but for whatever reason I can't populate a pre-existing array such as

```
MyFunctions2[x_, y_] := Array[f, 10]
```

with functions. For example the assignment

```
MyFunctions2[x_, y_][[1]] := A[x]
```

fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have the hang of functional assignment, but the following answer should be instructive.  Note that function definitions can be accessed via [DownValues](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

Proceeding to replace an assignment with `A[x]` using `z` as a placeholder.

```
A[x_] := 10 x;
B[y_] := 100 y;
MyFunctions[x_, y_] := {z, B[y]};

MyFunctions[1, 2]
```

> {z, 200}

The first parameter can be reassigned as `A[x]` like so.  Find the part in the downvalue to replace by finding the position of `z`:

```
pos = First[Position[DownValues[MyFunctions], z]]
```

> {1, 2, 1}

Replace the part in the downvalue.  Block `A` to prevent evaluation.

```
Block[{A},
  DownValues[MyFunctions] = ReplacePart[DownValues[MyFunctions], pos -> A[x]]];

MyFunctions[1, 2]
```

> {10, 200}

On the other hand, if you have an array of functions already set and wish to change an assignment:

```
A[x_] := 10 x;
B[y_] := 100 y;

MyFunctions2[0, 1] := {B[0], B[1]}
MyFunctions2[1, 2] := {B[1], B[2]}
MyFunctions2[2, 3] := {B[2], B[3]}
MyFunctions2[x_, y_] := {B[x], B[y]}

MyFunctions2[1, 2]
```

> {100, 200}

```
pos = First[Position[DownValues[MyFunctions2], Unevaluated[MyFunctions2[1, 2]]]]
```

> {2, 1, 1}

```
posarg = pos + {0, 1, 0}
```

> {2, 2, 1}

```
Block[{A},
 DownValues[MyFunctions2] = ReplacePart[DownValues[MyFunctions2], posarg -> A[1]]];

MyFunctions2[1, 2]
```

> {10, 200}

Comment: Hey Chris, I just wanted to say thank you; this was helpful. Out of your suggestions, I managed to come up with a method:

Comment: First, I declare the functions I want to populate an array with and I also declare an array; I use strings to populate the array entries temporarily. Then, with a While loop through this array MyArray, I replace the strings with Unevaluated[MyFunctions[x,y]] via If statements inside this while loop. I can finally evaluate the array of functions via While[{x=x0,y=y0},Evaluate[MyArray]]. It works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. :-)

Comment: @Walrus , if you have a good alternative answer to your own question go ahead and post it as an answer.  .. And don't forget to upvote answers you find useful.